# How to prevent Ajax long-poll from reloading div in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax

Edit: After some more research, I think I may be on the path to an answer, but I still need some help.   If I understand correctly, what's happening is that my php script is returning empty answers after querying the MySQL database and not finding anything, so instead of holding the request open, if it has nothing to send, it returns an empty answer to the get request, and the JavaScript I have just opens another request, resulting in a deviation from the expected "long-polling" behavior.   So, I now think the problem lies in my chatserver.php script.   How do I get it to stop returning empty answers?  The if(true){break;}else{continue;} thing is something I came across here when I was putting the chatserver script together originally, and I'm not sure I even understand why it works.

I'm working on a fairly large scale web application with an awful lot of stuff going on in it, and Chrome is causing me fits.  I'll try to explain my issue as concisely as possible, but there is a lot of code that goes into creating this issue.

I'm using a long-polling Ajax request that calls a php script to push messages back to a div in the client page.   Here's the Ajax code:

```
function poll(){
var messageListener = new XMLHttpRequest();
messageListener.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(messageListener.readyState==4 && messageListener.status==200){
        document.getElementById("main_view").innerHTML+=messageListener.responseText;
        document.getElementById("main_view").scrollTop = document.getElementById("main_view").scrollHeight;
        poll();
    }
}
messageListener.open("GET","chatserver.php",true);
messageListener.send();
}


poll();
```

As you can see, the function starts when the page loads, and on receiving a response, it runs again, so I always have a request open the server can use to push chat messages.   All of this is playing nicely in the latest versions of Chrome, IE and Firefox.   The problem comes when I send a link to the div with a CSS tooltip.  I have set pointer-events: none; as well as positioned and z-indexed all the elements in my CSS, such that the tooltips perform beautifully in IE and Firefox, but in Chrome, I get the infamous "tooltip flicker".

The chatserver.php script basically runs in an infinite while loop that queries the database for new chat messages and echoes them.

```
while(true){
    if(true){
    //query database for new messages and echo them
    break;
    } else {
    continue;
    }
}
```

The problem arises because Chrome seems to be constantly refreshing the "main_view" div every time the loop runs.   I can see this happening with "Inspect Element" in Chrome.   Other browsers don't update the div until there is actually new information.

Here's the css.

```
*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;

}
#view_wrapper{
width:1010px;
height:705px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;

}
#main_view{
position: relative;
z-index: 96;
width: 1000px;
height: 700px;
font-family: Lucida Console;
text-align: left;   
overflow: auto;
margin-right: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
pointer-events: none;
}

#command_line{

width: 964px;
height: 25px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
#submit{

width: 45px;
height: 25px;

}
#main_view a{
pointer-events: auto;
position:relative;
z-index:98;
}

#main_view a span{
pointer-events: none;
position:absolute;
z-index: 97;
}
.tooltip {outline:none; color: crimson; pointer-events: none;}
.tooltip strong {line-height:30px; color: crimson; pointer-events: none;}
.tooltip:hover {text-decoration:none; pointer-events: none;}
.tooltip span {
pointer-events: none; left:100%; bottom: 25%;
position:absolute; visibility:hidden; padding:10px;
width:300px; height: 110px;line-height:16px;
} 
.tooltip:hover span{
pointer-events: none;
position:absolute;  
border:2px solid #FFF;  color:#EEE;
background:#333 url(css-tooltip-gradient-bg.png) repeat-x 0 0;
border-radius:2px;        
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 4px #666;
visibility:visible; z-index:97;
}
```

The html structure of the page is basically:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <center>
    <div id="view_wrapper>
    <div id="main_view">
    </div>
    </div>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

If it's not apparent, what I'm attempting to do is recreate the functionality of an old-school MUD game entirely in a browser based format.   So far it's going well, apart from this annoying tooltip issue!   It'd be difficult to link you to my application as you would need to have an account and acquire some items to see the issue at play.  I'm not able to post images, but you can see a screenshot here:  http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v600/threadreaper/screenshot_zps8381bacb.jpg

Any ideas how to stop Chrome from constantly refreshing that div and making the tooltips flicker?

Comment: You're calling the function in the function, so its a never ending loop of reloading your div, lookup set timeout and delay the poll() call inside your function.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't really fix my issue.   It slows down the flicker in chrome, but also introduces lag into the chat, and breaks the chat completely in Internet Explorer.  I could maybe employ some browser hacks so the change is only applied to Chrome, but the chat server pushes more than just chat messages, and in the context of a game, it's important that these are delivered in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes my tooltip flickering issue:

```
function poll(){
var messageListener = new XMLHttpRequest();
messageListener.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(messageListener.readyState==4 && messageListener.status==200)    {

        if(messageListener.responseText.length != 0){
            document.getElementById("main_view").innerHTML+=messageListener.responseText;
            document.getElementById("main_view").scrollTop = document.getElementById("main_view").scrollHeight;
        }
        poll();
    }
    }
    messageListener.open("GET","chatserver.php",true);
    messageListener.send();
}
```

I still have the problem with Chrome opening a million GET requests as it gets empty answers from the PHP script, but as this is outside the scope of the original question, I will consider this one answered.

Comment: Consider looking into HTML5 websockets if you don't want to bombard your server with GET requests.

Comment: That is exactly the issue I'm looking into right now, thanks for the advice!